# Add view to Django only for testing (not in production)

Tags: django

I want to test my session handling. I wrote a view and a test for this, and everything is fine.

But I don't like the fact, that the URL is accessible in the production system, too.

Is there a simple way to make an view only available during testing. In the production system this URL should not be in known to the url-resolver.

It would be cool if the code which adds the url to urlpatterns would live in the test-code, and not in the production code. I would like the production code clean.

Answer (score 3):

A common pattern is to check for DEBUG in the urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings


if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

    # Serve static and media files from development server
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. It would be a bit cooler, if the code which adds the url to urlpatterns would live in the test-code, and not in the production code. I would like the production code clean.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate django app only for testing, and never upload it to production. If you are using git, you can keep it in another branch. So in producction server your code is "clean".

You don't have to create an app for testing, but I think is more organized this way.

Comment: Using a git branch feels a bit strange, but the idea with an extra app sounds good. Thank you